# Removing all non-word characters in a Cyrillic UTF-8 encoded String

Tags: java, string

Normally, in order to remove non-word characters from a String the `replaceAll` method can be used:

```
String cleanWords = "some string with non-words such as ';'".replaceAll("\\W", "");
```

The above returns a cleaned string **"somestringwithnonwordssuchas"**.

However, if the string contains Cyrillic characters they get recognised as non-word, and get removed from the string. It is expected that Cyrillic characters would remain. Hence the question.

What is a proper way to deal with the task of removing non-word characters regardless of the language, assuming that string has UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: It would be useful if your sample code actually contained some of the Cyrillic characters that you've got troubles with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `[^\\p{L}]`. That should match every Unicode codepoint except for letters.

The [`Pattern` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ubpc) has a pretty thorough description of the possible character classes. Note that the POSIX character classes are ASCII-only by default and won't help you a lot, you'll need to use the Unicode-specific classes.

Note that there's the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) that changes the behavior of the POSIX classes to conform to [this section of the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) (basically making them equivalent to their closest Unicode-aware equivalents).

Comment: The OP should check how they want digits to be handled, as I believe this will differ from the original.